# Go on telling something to see what happened next and stop going on doing that

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-request

We all know then when someone is going to ask you to continue their speech we can tell them:

> - Go on, tell me what happened next. [[Source]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/go-on)

But imagine they say something quite annoying or for some reasons you don't want them to continue telling you what they were talking about. What would you normally say in English? Does the sentence below sound natural to you?

> - Please don't go on.

If not, please let me know what is more acceptable to be said here?

P.S. would it be possible to use some verbs like: "proceed" or "continue" in this sense at all?

Comment: Why do you think it might not be possible?

Comment: I don't think about it's possibility. I thought maybe there is a more natural way to say the same thing in this case. I am a nonnative and do not feel your language. If you were me you could possibly notice why I am concerning about such a question. There are lots of lingual gaps between yours and mine @Clare.

Comment: What would be said depends on *why* you are telling them to stop.  You are glossing over the core issue: "for some reason you don't want them to continue". I will remove my vote-to-close because the question is too broad if you can edit it to be more specific.

Comment: @TRomano I mentioned above, but I think it was surely not sufficient to indicate the message in my mind. Well, suppose i.e. they say something very annoying that can hurt your feelings or something that is upsetting you, e.g. a fact about your (saving your presence) wife who is cheating you and they have faced that scene and so on. It can bother you too much to hear the rest of the story. So what shall you say here? I know that: "Please don't go on" is an idiomatic sentence in English, but is it natural in this sense?

Comment: Additional details need to be edited into your question.

Comment: @user3169 then one may assume that others have written something for themselves. It can be considered as a disrespect in my mind. If there is a polite way to edit the question, I would do that. I guess just mentioning "Added: lalala" would work. Do you agree?

Comment: You can add something like --EDIT-- at the bottom of the existing text, followed by any additional information. Then it will be clear to others what the added details are.

Answer (score 1):

In polite conversation, you could try to redirect the speaker.

`That sounds very interesting, but please tell me more about (other topic).`

or

`That is super, but I was hoping (other person) could tell us something about (other topic).`

You could say "please don't go on" with close friends, who would not take offense.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you want the person to stop will affect what you say. When you use the expression **go on about something**, it means that somebody keeps repeating the same complaint.

> John keeps **going on about** his new boss.

So, if somebody keeps repeating the same complaint, you can say

> Please don't **go on about** it.

If you find the subject distasteful or embarrassing, you would not use the **go on** expression. You could politely say

> Can we please change the subject?

Or (very much) less politely

> Just shut (the fuck) up!

Comment: Did I get you right @Java Latte? Did you mean "go on sth" means repeating the same thing continually?

Comment: @A-friend. Not **go on sth**, but **go on about sth**. It's not necessarily repetition: it;s more about keeping talking about the same subject, for example a Patriots fan might go on about the Patriots. It's mainly used when somebody is complaining about the same thing.